Why does this way to use Importance Sampling convergeant?
Reading on importance sampling here,
I understand that the expected value of a distribution can be found with
$$E_p[f] = \int f(x) p(x) dx$$ where x is sampled from $p$. And that we can simply multiply the numerator and denominator by another distribution q(x) and get the same result.
$$E_q[f] = \int f(x) \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} q(x) \; dx$$
This may improve converging time depending on the choice of $q$.
This can be approximated with
$$E_q[f] \approx \sum f(x) \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$
However, in Ray Tracing literature, I keep coming across this
$$E_{pdf}[f] \approx \sum  \frac{f(x)}{pdf(x)}$$
How are these equivalent?

After some time I understood.
In the context of ray tracing, we are interested in approximating The Rendering Equation. That is, we want to compute an integral of the form:
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = E[f]*(b-a) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i f(x_i) (b-a)$$
We can rewrite this with $p(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$:
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i f(x_i) (b-a) = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i \frac{f(x_i)}{p(x_i)}$$
This assumed that we uniformally sampled our $x_i$ in the interval $[a,b]$ so we our original integral was really $\int_a^b f(x) dx = E_p[f]*(b-a)$. Note that $p$ is a $PDF$, $p(x) \geq 0$, $\int_{a}^b p(x) dx = 1$. We can take a new PDF $q(x) \neq 0 \in [a,b]$  and write:
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{q(x)} q(x) dx = E_q[f/q]*(b-a) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_i \frac{f(x_i)}{q(x_i)} (b-a)$$
The important part is that $x$ is sampled from $q$ and not $p$.
